# How to generate links using anchor tag helpers for non-default routes?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying use ASP.NET Core MVC routing to serve this template:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "project",
    template: "{projectID}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
```

This works fine, the URL like `/1/accounts/index` passes `projectID` parameter to the `Index` action of `Accounts` controller.

However, I couldn't figure out how to generate links to this route with standard Tag Helpers.

I tried:

```
<a asp-route="project" asp-area="" asp-controller="Accounts" asp-action="Index" asp-route-projectID="1">Accounts</a>
```

but this results in the following error:

```
InvalidOperationException: Cannot determine the  'href' attribute for <a>. The following attributes are mutually  exclusive:  asp-route  asp-controller, asp-action  asp-page, asp-page-handler
```

In fact, the documentation explicitly states that I can't use `asp-route` with `asp-controller, asp-action  asp-page, asp-page-handler`.
For now I'm using the workaround:

```
@Url.RouteUrl("project", new { controller = "Accounts", action = "Index", projectID = 1 })
```

but how do I use Tag Helper to generate links for this route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not combine `asp-route="project"` and `asp-controller="Accounts"`, to achieve your requirement, try

```
<a asp-controller="Accounts" asp-action="Index" asp-route-projectID="1">Accounts</a>
```

And make sure that your "project" MapRoute defined before any other MapRoute.

Comment: This way you cannot choose which map route you want to use and this will depends on the order of the map routes. If you have multiple map routes and the first one is "{controller=Home}/{projectID}/{action=Index}/{id?}", you will end up getting "Accounts/1/Index" instead of "1/Accounts/Index"

Comment: I tried this, but it just appends query string `accounts?projectID=1`

Comment: Wait, this actually works. But the route config must come BEFORE my 'default' route. I'm not sure why though.

Comment: @Laksmono, yes, indeed I found it depends on the order of mapping. I believe the more specific routes must come before the least specific.